Playwright - Host system is missing dependencies like libicu70 to run webkit tests and can't install them
On Ubuntu 23
Chromium and Firefox tests pass but wekbit shows output below
Host system is missing dependencies to run browsers. ║
    ║ Missing libraries:                                   ║
    ║     libicudata.so.70                                 ║
    ║     libicui18n.so.70                                 ║
    ║     libicuuc.so.70                                   ║
    ║     libgstcodecparsers-1.0.so.0                      ║
    ║     libflite.so.1                                    ║
    ║     libflite_usenglish.so.1                          ║
    ║     libflite_cmu_grapheme_lang.so.1                  ║
    ║     libflite_cmu_grapheme_lex.so.1                   ║
    ║     libflite_cmu_indic_lang.so.1                     ║
    ║     libflite_cmu_indic_lex.so.1                      ║
    ║     libflite_cmulex.so.1                             ║
    ║     libflite_cmu_time_awb.so.1                       ║
    ║     libflite_cmu_us_awb.so.1                         ║
    ║     libflite_cmu_us_kal16.so.1                       ║
    ║     libflite_cmu_us_kal.so.1                         ║
    ║     libflite_cmu_us_rms.so.1                         ║
    ║     libflite_cmu_us_slt.so.1                         ║
    ║     libx264.so                 

Installing dependencies also gives:
$ npx playwright install-deps
Installing dependencies...
Switching to root user to install dependencies...
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease                                            
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease                                          
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                             
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease                                  
Ign:6 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:7 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu mantic Release
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libicu70
E: Unable to locate package libffi7
E: Unable to locate package libx264-163
Failed to install browser dependencies
Error: Installation process exited with code: 100


As a work-around use the canary version: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/30368#issuecomment-2147091537
# Ubuntu 24.04 - Use canary version until v1.45 is released
npx playwright@next install
npx playwright@next install-deps


For me, updating @playwright/test 1.44.1 → 1.45.1 did the trick. (Ubuntu 24.04, Node.js 20, npm 10).

This might be an issue with Ubuntu 23.04 which is not a LTS version.
Their suggestion to use 24.04 LTS
However I just installed 24.04 LTS and the problem remains

i came here cause i experienced this error on 24.04...

One workaroound if you are ok with skipping webkit for now is to chage the config, playwright.config.js commenting out
//  name: 'webkit',
//  use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] },
//},

now I at least get passing tests for Chrome and Firefox

