Playwright tests in Github actions error for webkit with "host system is missing dependencies to run browsers"
When doing Playwright (v1.47) tests on webkit in Github actions, I suddenly get an error: Error: browserType.launch: Host system is missing dependencies to run browsers.
The runner is using Ubuntu 24.04 (due to ubuntu-latest) and neither chromium nor firefox show this error.
The full error message is as follows:
 1) [webkit] › pages/index.spec.ts:4:5 › The landing page › contains an organism ──────────────────

    Error: browserType.launch: 
    ╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
    ║ Host system is missing dependencies to run browsers. ║
    ║ Missing libraries:                                   ║
    ║     libicudata.so.70                                 ║
    ║     libicui18n.so.70                                 ║
    ║     libicuuc.so.70                                   ║
    ║     libvpx.so.7                                      ║
    ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

How to fix this issue?

Related question (but not duplicate as it uses older Ubuntu 23 and Playwright 1.44): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78483400/playwright-host-system-is-missing-dependencies-like-libicu70-to-run-webkit-tes

This error appears to be happening for a lot of people who are using Ubuntu 24.04 and playwright 1.47, see recent comments on this issue, e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/30368#issuecomment-2412418303
There appear to be 2 options to fix it:

Upgrade Playwright to 1.48 or,
Downgrade Ubuntu to 22.04.

I tried upgrading and it worked. Others seem to have successfully pinned Ubuntu instead.
